# Function Calling Python basic

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter values from the tuple `('a',1), ('b',2),('c',3)` into the function `dostuff` but i always get a return of `None` or `False`. i'm new to this to i'm sorry if this question is basic. I would appreciate any help.

I expect the result of this to be:

```
a1---8
b2---8 
c3---8
```

Code:

```
def dostuff(stri,numb,char):
        cal = stri+str(numb)+'---'+str(char)
        return cal

def callit (tups,char):
    for x in range(len(tups)):
        dostuff(tups[x][0],tups[x][1],char)

print(callit([('a',1), ('b',2),('c',3)],8))
```

Comment: callit returns none because you have no explicit return

Comment: since you wrote `print(callit())` I suppose `callit` should return a string. What should it return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the `return` value of the functions: unless otherwise specified, all functions will return `None` at completion.  Your code:

```
print(callit([('a',1), ('b',2),('c',3)],8))`
```

is telling the Python interpreter "print the return value of this function call."  This isn't printing what you expect it to because the `callit` function doesn't have a return value specified.  You could either change the `return` in your `dostuff` function like so:

```
 def dostuff(stri,numb,char):
    cal = stri+str(numb)+'---'+str(char)
    print cal

def callit (tups,char):
    for x in range(len(tups)):
        dostuff(tups[x][0],tups[x][1],char)

callit([('a',1), ('b',2),('c',3)],8)
```

This changes the return on the third line into a print command, and removes the print command from the `callit` call.
Another option would be:

```
 def dostuff(stri,numb,char):
    cal = stri+str(numb)+'---'+str(char)
    return cal

def callit (tups,char):
    for x in range(len(tups)):
        cal = dostuff(tups[x][0],tups[x][1],char)
        print(cal)


callit([('a',1), ('b',2),('c',3)],8)
```

This takes the return value from the `dostuff` function and stores it in a variable named cal, which could then be printed or written to a file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

as @n1c9 said, every Python function must return some object, and if there's no `return` statement written in the function definition the function will **implicitly** return the `None` object. (implicitly meaning that under the hood, Python will see that there's no return statement and return`None`)

However, while there's nothing wrong in this case with printing a value in a function rather than returning it, it's generally considered bad practice. This is because if you ever want to test the function to aid in debugging, you have to write the test within the function definition. While if you returned the value you could just test the return value of calling the function.

So when you're debugging this code you might write something like this:

```
def test_callit():
    tups = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
    expected = 'a1---8\nb2---8\nc3---8'
    result = callit(tups, 8)
    assert result == expected, (str(result) + " != " + expected)
```

if you're unfamiliar with the assert statement, you can read up about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assert_stmt)

Now that you have a test function, you can go back and modify your code. Callit needs a return value, which in this case should probably be a string. so for the function`callit` you might write

```
def callit(tups, char):
    result = ''
    for x in range(len(tups)):
        result += dostuff(tups[x][0], tups[x][1], char) + '\n'
    result = result[:result.rfind('\n')] # trim off the last \n
    return result
```

when you run test_callit, if you get any assertion errors you can see how it differs from what you expect in the traceback.

What I'm about to talk about isn't really relevant to your question, but I would say improves the readability of your code.

Python's for statement is very different from most other programming languages, because it actually acts like a foreach loop. Currently, the code ignores that feature and forces regular for-loop functionality. it's actually simpler and faster to write something like this:

```
def callit(tups, char):
    result = ''
    for tup in tups:
        result += dostuff(tup[0], tup[1], char) + '\n'
    result = result[:result.rfind('\n')] # trim off the last \n
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

For a function to return a value in python it must have a `return` statement. In your `callit` function you lack a value to `return`. A more Pythonic approach would have both a value and iterate through the tuples using something like this:

```
def callit(tups, char):
    x = [dostuff(a, b, char) for a, b in tups]
    return x
```

Since `tups` is a list of tuples, we can iterate through it using `for a, b in tups` - this grabs both elements in the pairs. Next `dostuff(a, b, char)` is calling your `dostuff` function on each pair of elements and the `char` specified. Enclosing that in brackets makes the result a list, which we then return using the `return` statement.

Note you don't need to do:

```
x = ...
return x
```

You can just use `return [dostuff(a, b, char) for a, b in tups]` but I used the former for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension to do it in one line:

```
char = 8
point_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2),('c', 3)]
print("\n".join(["{}{}---{}".format(s, n, char) for s, n in point_list]))
```

`"{}{}---{}".format(s, n, char)` creates a string by replacing `{}` by each one of the input in `format`, therefore `"{}{}---{}".format("a", 1, 8)` will return `"a1---8"`

`for s, n in point_list` will create an implicit loop over the `point_list` list and for each element of the list (each tuple) will store the first element in `s` and the second in `n`

`["{}{}---{}".format(s, n, char) for s, n in point_list]` is therefore a list created by applying the format we want to each of the tuples: it will return `["a1---8","b2---8","c3---8"]`

finally `"\n".join(["a1---8","b2---8","c3---8"])` creates a single string from a list of strings by concatenating each element of the list to "\n" to the next one: `"a1---8\nb2---8\nc3---8"` (`"\n"` is a special character representing the end of a line

Comment: It's not very helpful to give a one-liner without explaining it to a user who is confused about the return value of a function.

Comment: How does this help the OP? He is confused about function calling and returning. he didn't ask for a more concise way to do it.

Comment: @VincentSavard I edited my answer to explain each step